# Problema al compilar Invertir contenido de una lista

Tags: c++, lista

He hecho un ejercicio de listas que no me sale, es este:

> Desarrollar  el método    template   `<class T>  void    dll_t<T>::invert(void)` que     invierte    el  orden   de  los     valores     de  una     lista   sobre  ella    misma   (sin    usar    lista   auxiliar).

este es el código:

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include "dll_node_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

namespace AED {

    template <class T>
    class dll_t {
    private:
        dll_node_t<T>* head_;
        dll_node_t<T>* tail_;

        int sz_;

    public:
        dll_t(void);
        dll_t(const dll_t& L);
        virtual ~dll_t(void); 

        void insert_tail(dll_node_t<T>*);
        void insert_head(dll_node_t<T>*);

        dll_node_t<T>* extract_tail(void);
        dll_node_t<T>* extract_head(void);

        dll_node_t<T>* get_tail(void);
        dll_node_t<T>* get_head(void);

        bool empty(void) const ;
        int get_nz (void) const{}

        void unlink(dll_node_t<T>*);


        int get_size(void) const; // esto: contar los nonzeros
        //modif: suma elementos matriz 

        double suma (void) const; // esto pa arriba


        int get_np (void) const;
        double suma_mat (void) const;
        void invert(void);




        ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
    };

    template<class T> //ATENCION: DE AQUÍ A ABAJO ES LO QUE HECHO YO Y QUE NO ME COMPILA

    void dll_t<T> :: invert(void){

        dll_node_t<T>* aux = get_tail();

        while (aux != NULL){
            dll_t.extract_tail(aux);
            aux = aux -> get_prev();
        }

        while (aux !=NULL){
            dll_t.insert_tail(aux);
            aux=aux->get_next();
        }
    }
```

MI DUDA: Los errores que no logro entender AL COMPILAR son estos:

```
In member function 'void AED::dll_t<T>::invert()':
64  12      [Error] expected unqualified-id before '.' token
69  9       [Error] expected unqualified-id before '.' token
```

Es el main, para la nueva función que puse, no cambié nada ahí:

```
#include "dll_pair_t.hpp"

#define N_CHARS 26

using namespace std;
using namespace AED;

int main(void)
{

    dll_pair_t pair_list;
    dll_pair_t pair_list2;  




    node_pair_t* n = NULL;

    n = new node_pair_t(sparse_pair_t(5, 25.0));
    pair_list.insert_tail(n);

    n = new node_pair_t(sparse_pair_t(10, 35.0));
    pair_list.insert_tail(n);

    n = new node_pair_t(sparse_pair_t(25, 45.0));
    pair_list.insert_tail(n);

    // Lista 2

    n = new node_pair_t(sparse_pair_t(200, 1.0));
    pair_list2.insert_tail(n);

    n = new node_pair_t(sparse_pair_t(300, 1.0));
    pair_list2.insert_tail(n);



    dll_rara_pair_t lista_rara;
    node_raro_t* r = NULL;

    r = new node_raro_t(raro_pair_t(1, pair_list));
    lista_rara.insert_tail(r);

    r = new node_raro_t(raro_pair_t(5, pair_list2));
    lista_rara.insert_tail(r);

    lista_rara.write(cout); 

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Los que por ver que no aclare algo en la pregunta,se dediquen a gritar y casi faltar el respeto les voy a reportar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se localiza en estas instrucciones:

```
dll_t.extract_tail(aux);
dll_t.insert_tail(aux);
```

En tu caso `dll_t` es el **nombre** de la clase, seguramente querías llamar a las funciones `extract_tail` e `insert_tail`, para ello, dado que estás dentro de una función de la propia clase (`dll_t::invert`) no necesitas anteponer el nombre de la clase:

```
void dll_t<T> :: invert(void){

    dll_node_t<T>* aux = get_tail();

    while (aux != NULL){
        extract_tail(aux); // <--- sin dll_t.
        aux = aux -> get_prev();
    }

    while (aux !=NULL){
        insert_tail(aux); // <--- sin dll_t.
        aux=aux->get_next();
    }
}
```

Por cierto, en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), cuando una función no recibe parámetros, no es necesario indicar `void` en su lista de parámetros, puedes dejar dicha lista vacía:

```
    dll_t();
    virtual ~dll_t(); 
    dll_node_t<T>* extract_tail();
    dll_node_t<T>* extract_head();
    dll_node_t<T>* get_tail();
    dll_node_t<T>* get_head();
    bool empty() const ;
    int get_nz () const{}
    int get_size() const;
    double suma () const;
    int get_np () const;
    double suma_mat () const;
    void invert();

    // etc...
```